# Geotiff Rotation Python/GDAL/QGIS

Tags: python, gdal, qgis, geotiff, rasterio

I am trying to rotate geotifs by different amounts in python, GDAl and/or QGIS and keep the georeference information the same.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [modifying the GeoTransform](https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html). If you want to modify a GDAL image "in-place" (i.e. without creating a new image), you can open it in read-write mode:

```
from osgeo import gdal
Image = gdal.Open('ImageName.tif', 1)  # 1 = read-write, 0 = read-only
GeoTransform = Image.GetGeoTransform()
```

The GeoTransform is a tuple containing the following attributes:
(UpperLeftX, PixelSizeX, RowRotation, UpperLeftY, ColRotation, -PixelSizeY)

Tuples are immutable in Python, so to modify the GeoTransform you will have to convert it into a list, then revert back again into a tuple before writing it to the GDAL image:

```
GeoTransform = list(GeoTransform)
GeoTransform[2] = 0.0 # set the new RowRotation here!
GeoTransform[-2] = 0.0 # set the new ColRotation here!
GeoTransform = tuple(GeoTransform)
Image.SetGeoTransform(GeoTransform)  # write GeoTransform to image
del Image  # close the dataset
```